# Real-life use cases of scala-async?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, concurrency, future

Today I looked into implementing something really basic using [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/async), namely, a retry loop for a function that might fail.

Firstly, I couldn't use `await()` in a `try/catch` block; well fine, that was expected I guess; so I converted the function to return a `Future[Try[T]]` instead, which of course under normal circumstances is redundant as `Future[T]` already contains any exceptions but allowed me to call `isSuccess` on the return value instead of `try/catch`.

I then went on to try to implement the looping logic. a nested recursive `iter()` was out of question (again, as expected) because `await()` cannot be used in nested functions. Going with a good old `while` initially led me to success as I was actually experimenting with a `Future[Try[Unit]]` function so I didn't care about the return value; however, as soon as I changed to `Future[Try[Int]]` and hence started caring about the return value, I needed to save the `Try[Int]` I got out from the `await()` call so as to not only be able to check it if `isSuccess` but also return its contents. However, as soon as I tried `val ret = await(...)` I got an error saying:

> `await must not be used under a by-name argument`

So my question is, given (at least) these 3 limitations the last of which I'd say is extremely limiting, to the extent of at least seemingly rendering scala-async useless for any real life code apart from carefully chosen examples such as `await(x) + await(y)`, what are the currently known useful real life applications of this library?

Comment: Some feed back at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/dmVuwpfZQ40/Kp5Zm-AWazYJ .  I needed a paragraph of something sounding smart and dense, so I quoted you. It got retronym out of bed to answer, too.

Comment: +1 because it's a real question and everyone seems to be in tldr; mode. Or, possibly, there are no use cases.

Comment: That's cool; was that an April's fool's joke that ended up getting serious answers or what?

Comment: My personal favorite part was "buying SO rep with bit coins" and misspelling "Aadriaan Moors". And maybe flappy bird sending progress tweets. It was the end of April 1, PST, so one tries not to say anything unintentionally cruel. To be honest, I watched the scala-async video a long time ago but have never tried it out. On my todo list. If I get to it soon, I'll try to come up with a real answer for you (by next April 1).

Comment: no hurry there—a year of waiting is just fine; I'll just stick to composing Futures till then, even though it is much less readable, especially having been a heavy user of [Gevent](http://gevent.org) in the not so distant past.

Comment: Agreed. I got stopped by `await must not be used under a nested function` error. it makes scala-async quite useless.